# Unable to Append KNeighborsClassifier Predictions to a List

Tags: python, list

```
X = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
y = df['col4']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
predictions = []
    
for i in range(len(X_test)):
        num = knn.predict(X_test.iloc[i])[0]
        predictions.append(num)
```

**When I append to my list, I get the following error:**

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:395:
> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
> and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
> X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
> if it contains a single sample.   DeprecationWarning)

Comment: that’s a warning, not an error. in any case the warning is about the line where you call predict

Answer (score 0):

`predict` method takes a 2D array (or DataFrame) and you are giving it a 1D array. Try using `X_test.iloc[i].values.reshape(1,-1)` instead of `X_test.iloc[i]`.

By the way, you can direclty use `predictions = knn.predict(X_test)`, instead of looping through each value of X_test.